# Как сформировать бету через ispmanager?

Tags: администрирование, ispmanager, битрикс

Есть сайт на vps, мне дали доступ только к панели ispmager, как мне полностью сделать клон сайта www.site.ru на beta.site.ru , чтобы там можно было сделать своего фтп пользователя и работать уже без рисков на нем? сайт на битриксе, не будет ли ругаться лицензия, что я использую одну лицензию на 2 домена? 
Опишите пожалуйста полный список шагов, от А до Я , или скиньте почитать что нибудь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лицензия ispmanager выдается на айпи адрес, а не на домен. Заведите www-домен beta.site.ru и скопируйте в папку www-домена(скорее всего `/var/www/data/user/www/beta.site.ru`) нужные файлы. Далее создайте фтп пользователя с указанием принадлежности к этому www-домену. Пользователь тогда будет иметь доступ только к этой папке(`/var/www/data/user/www/beta.site.ru`).

Comment: Вы неверно ответили. Лицензия 1С-Битрикс выдается не на домен, и не на ip. Лицензия выдается на ключ, вы можете использовать один ключ для создания двух сайтов как угодно: на разных серверах (разные ip серверов), на разных доменах и т.п..

Comment: Я писал о лицензии ispmanager

Comment: тогда уточняйте о какой лицензии идет речь. из поста следует, что вопрос о лицензии битрикс. причем тогда битрикс к вашему вопросу вообще не ясно

Comment: Да спасибо, большое, понял суть. про битрикс я спрашивал потому что они вроде как запрещают "копировать" ядро. Только все равно не пойму, если у меня допустим редакция "старт", и там 2 сайта разных, я уже не смогу сделать беты для этих сайтов? т.к редакция позволяет только 2 сайта использовать?

Comment: К сожалению с битрикс я не работал, не могу подсказать в этом вопросе.

Comment: @alias Подскажите ещё, вот я создал домен , склоонировал туда файлы но сайт почему то не открывается http://beta.mineralplus.ru/ ,
Не удается найти DNS address сервера beta.mineralplus.ru.
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: нужно настроить dns записи, если у вас сторонний днс, то там.

Comment: @alias вроде один ип для все сайтов, зашел в доменные имена там вроде все настроено, настроек мало http://skrinshoter.ru/s/280416/sdBtv5?a

и ещё в самих www доменах такая штука http://skrinshoter.ru/s/280416/2XOk80?a, вроде тоже все норм?

Comment: @ЕгорТрегубенко firstvds выдает панель управления днс, там нужно прописать поддомен.